# How to log with Nlog in SpecFlow?

Tags: c#, nlog, specflow, xunit

SpecFlow writes its output into Console like this:

```
Given the "TestOperator" user is logged in
-> done: WebUserSteps.GivenTheUserIsLoggedIn("TestOperator", "") (9.5s)
```

How can we make it use NLog to configure where it should write?

With this:

```
public class CustomListener : ITraceListener
{
    private Logger Log = LogManager.GetLogger("SPECFLOW");

    public void WriteTestOutput(string message)
    {
        Log.Trace(message);
    }

    public void WriteToolOutput(string message)
    {
        Log.Trace(message);
    }
}
```

And

```
[Binding]
public class ScenarioContextInitializer 
{
    private readonly IObjectContainer _container;

    public ScenarioContextInitializer(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        _container = (scenarioContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(scenarioContext))).ScenarioContainer;
    }

    [Before]
    protected void Load()
    {
        _container.RegisterTypeAs<CustomListener, ITraceListener>();
    }
}
```

It didn't work. I know there is ability to add [plugins](http://specflow.org/documentation/Plugins/) but that seems too much overhead.

Also we use [ObjectivityLtd Test.Automation](https://github.com/ObjectivityLtd/Test.Automation) extensions.

It works via xunit tests generated by [SpecFlow.xUnit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpecFlow.xUnit)

Comment: did any of these answers not help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361281/how-to-set-up-individual-tracing-logging-with-specflow

Comment: @SamHolder No. Plugins look like overhead. And `trace.listener` was removed.

Comment: There is an [answer specifically for 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39109048/97614) (which probably isn't significantly different to latest version) and in the time you wait for someone else to figure it out for you, you could have written a plugin and have it working :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that NLog cannot find it's config.

When running unit tests, the dlls are moved and not the nlog.config

There are multiple solutions:

Load the config from a fixed path, e.g.

```
LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration("c:/mydir/nlog.config");
```

Or setup from code instead of config, e.g.:

```
var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
config.AddRuleForAllLevels(new FileTarget()
{
    FileName = "c:/temp/logfile.log"
});
LogManager.Configuration = config; //apply config
```

See [wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API)

If that is still an issue, check the [internal log](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging)

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar thing in my framework with this workaround:

- Add hook [AfterStep], that calls Console.WriteLine() [or your logger] with the name of the step + if passed or not (if test error != null, that means failed, o.w passed)
  Please note that this works perfect in parallel execution. (the correct output goes to each test)

Here is the example:
https://github.com/LirazShay/SpecFlowDemo/blob/master/src/SpecFlowDemo/Hooks.cs

Something like this:

```
 [AfterStep]
 public void LogStepResult()
        {
          string stepText = StepContext.StepInfo.StepDefinitionType + " " + StepContext.StepInfo.Text;
          Console.WriteLine(stepText);
          var stepTable = StepContext.StepInfo.Table;
          if (stepTable != null && stepTable.ToString() != "") Console.WriteLine(stepTable);
          var error = ScenarioContext.TestError;
          Console.WriteLine(error != null ? "-> error: " + error.Message : "-> done.");
        }
```